# nest-casl assertAbility() throws 401

Tags: authentication, nestjs, authorization, casl

The function "assertAbility" on AccessService always throws a 401 Unauthorized error (hasAbility returns false). The code below is pretty much identical to the provided [sample](https://github.com/getjerry/nest-casl#access-service-global) in the documentation. When I use the decorators, everything works as expected. What could cause this weird behavior?

NOT WORKING:

```
constructor(private readonly accessService: AccessService) {}

@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
@Query(() => User, { nullable: true })
async user(@Args("id") id: string, @CaslUser() userProxy: UserProxy<AuthUser>) {
  const user = await userProxy.get();
  const subject = this.userService.findById(id);

  this.accessService.assertAbility(user, Actions.read, subject);

  return subject;
}
```

WORKING:

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard, AccessGuard)
@UseAbility(Actions.read, User, UserHook)
...
```

Permissions:

```
user({ user, can }) {
  can(Actions.read, User, { id: user.id });
  can(Actions.update, User, { id: user.id });
  can(Actions.delete, User, { id: user.id });
}
```